# how to convert object into array in typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular7

I am trying to display a result of web service which is JSON in my ionic project. I can recieve it and display in console, But I can't display it in HTML view. This is my code :

service.ts

```
 searchPerson(admin: AdminInfo): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.post<Person[]>(this.personServiceApi, admin, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap((newRequest: Person[]) => {
        console.log(`fetched persons` + newRequest);}),
        catchError(this.handleError<Person[]>('fetched persons'))
    );
  }
```

menupage.ts:

```
  this.loginService.searchPerson(this.admin).subscribe((persons: Person []) => {
          if (Array.isArray(persons)) { // checks if persons is an array
              this.persons = persons;
              } else {
              console.error('persons in not an array');
              console.log('Type of persons is : ' + typeof persons);
              console.log('Persons:');
              console.log(persons);
              }
      });
```

menupage.html

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let person of persons">
     <p>{{person.Address}}</p>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

This is the result in console :

```
fetched persons[object Object]
persons in not an array
Type of persons is : object
Persons:
{GetAllPersonResult: Array(41)}
  GetAllPersonResult: Array(41)
    0: {Address: "", Barcode: "", BirthDate: "",CertificateNo: "", Charge: , 
       …}
    1: {Address: "",Barcode: "", BirthDate: "",CertificateNo: "", Charge: , 
          …}
    2: {Address: "", Barcode: "", BirthDate: "", CertificateNo: "", Charge: 
       , …}
    3: {Address: "", Barcode: "", BirthDate: "",CertificateNo: "", Charge: , 
          …}
    4: {Address: "", Barcode: "",BirthDate: "", CertificateNo: "", Charge: , 
        …}
    …………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….


    40: {Address: "", Barcode: "", BirthDate: "", CertificateNo: "", Charge: 
        , …}
4.  length: 41
5.  __proto__: Array(0)
2.  __proto__: Object
```

[image]

Comment: You need to set the type in subscribe method: Person[]

Comment: Could you please explain it more.I didn't undrestand.

Comment: Check my answer please

Comment: Your http server doesn't return a JSON array. It returns a JSON object. Check the response in the network panel of your browser dev tools. Or just look at what is printed in the console.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: you're right.persons is not an array.it is an object.how can i convert object into an array? I've added the output again to the top

Comment: Post the JSON you receive from the server.

Comment: Do you mean that the output should be turned on in the service?Can you write code for me? Because I'm new in ionic.

Comment: No. I mean that, in order to know the structure of the object you receive, I need you to post the JSON you receive from the server in your question.

Comment: Ok.I posted th JSON I receive from the serve.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the culprit is `persons` not being an `array`. Try this code and watch your console for error

```
this.loginService.searchPerson(this.admin).subscribe((persons: Person[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(persons)) { // checks if persons is an array
    this.persons = persons;
  } else {
    console.error('persons in not an array');
    // this.persons = [persons];
    this.persons = [];
  }
});
```